# Field Recording Equipment 

Tags: recording, equipment

I am a Novice Sound Designer and would like to do field recording to build my own personal library of sounds.  I am looking for some advise on which recording equipment and microphones I should purchase to get me started?

Comment: Can we add to this question, "I would also like to build a small kit to record production audio, what is the minimum effective setup for a novice like myself who wants to break into recording dialogue and sound on set?"

Comment: @Carmine Do you have a budget?

Comment: Yes, $1000-$1500.  

Answer (score 8):

@Carmine & @Chris,

There are a number of questions similar to both of yours that have gone into this topic.

Like:
[Needing some advice for a small budget sound recording setup...](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/needing-some-advice-for-a-small-budget-sound-recording-setup)

or :
[Budget not large, really need to get an on location sound kit together for a possible job!](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/300/budget-not-large-really-need-to-get-an-on-location-sound-kit-together-for-a-poss)

Starting to the right under the "Related" column heading will get you going. The content is dynamic and changes for every question page, so it can lead you straight down the rabbit hole.

When you have more specific inquiries, use the search bar at the top right of the screen or click the Tags button in the menu bar at the top of this page to see if a question similar to your own has already been asked.

Comment: @Steve, nice! :-)

Comment: Not as nice as @Tim! :) http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/gear-for-starting-out-field-recording

Answer (score 1):

The **Zoom H4n** is a versatile, easy-to-use, reliable piece of equipment at a very reasonable price. Highly recommend it; however, there are many other options...i'd look at the specs. and read into them. There ultimately is no correct answer...just depends on your preferences and price range.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I've looked at the Zoom H4n and I think I am going to get something a little studier,  I do appreciated your input.

Carmine

Answer (score 1):

Nice blog article here: http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/gear-for-starting-out-field-recording